# How to prevent people from keep looping HTTP POST to a function?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to develop a website, the website got a pop-up modal which allows the user to subscribe to our latest promotion. In that input, we got a textbox to allow users to key in their email.

However, when we look at the HTML code, the HTTP POST URL is visible:

[image]

If someone is trying to use this URL, and spam HTTP POST requests (see below), unlimited entries can be created in the `subscriber` database table.

```
for (int a = 0; a < 999999; a++)
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "email", a+"@gmail.com" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening? We cannot put a capcha, since this is subscriber to our promotion.

**Edit:** Please note that a ANTI-forgery token will not work, because the hacker can download entire HTML string using GET, and get the value from the anti forgery token textbox and POST the value to the POST URL again, so it will not work and the same anti-forgery token can use multiple times, it is not secure.

Comment: is it required to have an account to register to the promotion ?

Comment: no need, just anyone who saw the page , and if he interested to our websites, he can subscriber for our newsletter

Comment: Maybe you could check the ip of the user and it the ip has already subscribed to this promotion don't add the new email ?

Comment: @ryan1555 anti forgery tokens only safe guard you from CSRF not from duplicate request, I can pass same anti forgery request any number of times to submit any request. For example using tool like fiddler, I can post a data any number of time using same antiforgery token.

Comment: @PSK what will be your suggestion

Comment: @ryan1555 I have already posted my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose one of the below option to implement what you are looking for.

1- Implement `CAPTCHA/re-CAPTCHA`, it will make sure that using any tool request can't be made. I understand that you don't want to use CAPTCHA, I still feel you should go with it, as it is the best approach to handle this type of scenarios.

2- **IP Based restriction**, lock submitting the request from one IP for some time.

3- Other option can be **OTP (one time password**), you can send the OTP to the email, and only after successful verification you can register the email.

Answer (score 4):

Use **AntiForgeryToken**. Read more about Antiforgery Tokens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955766/what-is-the-html-antiforgerytoken-helper-function-for)

1. In your form Razor View, Add an `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` as a form field.

   ```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

       <div class="form-horizontal">
           @*Rest of the form*@
   }
   ```
2. In your Action Method use `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Edit( MyViewModel form)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
          // Rest of ur code
       }
    }
   ```